# Assign the value of table header to corresponding columns using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to assign the value/text of header column to its corresponding data column records using jQuery/JavaScript?

Like 
id columns should have id header value,and English columns should have English header value etc.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. How to know that which column is for which kind of data ? You have already shown column header.

Comment: I just want to keep the header value along with column,e.g: in english column i want to show Test English and so on

Comment: so id column should have `id 1`, `id 2` like that ?

Comment: id columns would have 1_id,2_id,3_id and so on.
All i want to attach/append the text of header to columns.

Comment: Yes it can be like this  id 1, id 2 @HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: You should give html code snippet to show structure of the table then I can help.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay,please have a look at this https://kopy.io/hgts8

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is your solution:

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $('tr').find('td').each(function(i){
                var ind = $(this).index();
                var text = $(this).text();
                var header_text = $('thead > tr').find('th:eq('+ind+')').text();
                $(this).text(header_text+': '+text);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hi @Khirad Banu, if you got your required solution with this answer, then can you please accept this answer?